# ping constantly an IP and write into txt

Tags: python, cmd, ping

I have this code

```
def ping_google(command):
    with open('google.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(subprocess.check_output(command))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=ping_anel, args=("ping -t 8.8.8.8",))
```

And i would like to save the infinite pinging to google in a txt file. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't need Python for this.  You can do this at a command line directly.  `ping -t 8.8.8.8 >> google.txt`.  But what's the point?  Ping doesn't output the time of day.  What will you learn from this?

Comment: @TimRoberts I know that i can do it from CMD directly but i would like to do it with python because later on i will need to manipulate some data

Answer (score 0):

```
command = "ping -i20 8.8.8.8  > ping.txt"
```

Ask `subprocess` to execute that with `, shell=True`,
and you're done.
It will append three status reports each minute, forever,
or until you hit CTRL/C.

(I expect [ping](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)
to require a [time-to-live](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1) value after a `-t` switch,
so I'm not sure what the intent of your command was.)

Comment: [ping](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) for the Windows command line isn't the same. `-t` pings the specified host until stopped. The `-i <ttl>` switch seems to do what you describe for the  linux-`ping -t` on Windows.